# Connecting tap bridges to virtual machines

Tags: linux-kernel, virtual-machine, vmware, ns-3

I have 2 virtual machines which need to communicate each other. They are created on VMware. When i write "ping virtual machine 2" on virtual machine 1, request should go eth0 of virtual machine 1, tap bridge 1, tap bridge 2 and eth0 of virtual machine 2.

I need to connect virtual machine 1 to virtual machine 2 through ns3 network simulator. I created tap bridges through ns3 by using the example code http://www.nsnam.org/doxygen/tap-csma_8cc_source.html. Tap bridges were created on other virtual machine called simulator. 
Now, I need to connect these taps to network adapters (eth0) of virtual machines. Thus, I can reach virtual machine 2 from virtual machine 1.

Simulator also have 2 network adapters eth1 and eth 2 that may use to connect to virtual machines.

How can i connect them?

IP adresses:

```
virtual machine 1 eth0 192.168.221.10 gateway 192.168.221.1   
virtual machine 2 eth0 192.168.222.10 gateway 192.168.222.1    
eth1 192.168.221.1    
eth2 192.168.222.1    
tap1 192.1.1.1    
tap2 192.1.1.2
```

Answer (score 2):

check VMWare networking for details . It supports 4 main types bridged, hostonly, NAT & virtual network. you can either bridge a physical interface on the virtual machines or create a virtual network in vmware and add both vms ethx interfaces to it.